# Lagrange Multipliers Method to finding the minimum and the maximum in the unit circle for quadratic curve

Tags: maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I am just studying mathematics and I have a task to solve it...

There are a quadratic curve: $F(x,y) =$ $a_{o}$ + $a_{1}$x + $a_{2}$y + $a_{3}x^2$ + $a_{4}y^2$ + $a_{5}xy$

and a cirle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

All coefficients are known.

I tried to find minimum by Lagrange Multiplier:

$\nabla  f(x,y)=  <a_{1} + 2a_{3}x + a_{5}y, a_{2} + 2a_{4}y + a_{5}x>$

$\lambda\nabla g(x,y) = \lambda<2x,2y>$

Now i have a system of equations:

$a_{1} + 2a_{3}x + a_{5}y - 2\lambda x = 0$

$a_{2} + 2a_{4}y + a_{5}x - 2\lambda y = 0$

$x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$

From eq.2:

$y = \frac{{2\lambda x - 2a_{3}x - a_{1}}}{a_{5}}$

Substitute to eq. 1:

$a_{2}a_{5} + 4a_{4}\lambda x - 4a_{3}a_{2}x - 2a_{4}a_{1} - 4\lambda^2x + 4\lambda a_{3}x + 2\lambda a_{1} = 0$

And after this substituting I don't know which next step...

O.K. I tried next approach:

From $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ lets $x = cos(\theta)$ and $y = sin(\theta)$ then

$F(\theta) =$ $a_{o}$ + $a_{1}cos(\theta)$ + $a_{2}sin(\theta)$ + $a_{3}cos^2(\theta$) + $a_{4}sin^2(\theta)$ + $a_{5}cos(\theta) sin(\theta)$

$F_{(\theta)} = a_{5}(cos^2(\theta) - sin^2(\theta)) + 2(a_{4} - a_{3}) sin(\theta)cos(\theta) + a_{2}cos(\theta) - a_{1}sin(\theta) = 0$

And in this approach I can't solve equation...

Maybe you have some hints?

Comment: When you wrote $a_4^2$, did you mean $a_4y^2$? And another thing. You wrote “I tried to solve it by Lagrange Multiplier”. Which problem did you try to solve?

Comment: You are solving an optimization problem. In the system of equations (KKT) you have 3 equations and 3 unknowns.

Comment: "All coefficients are known" was anything about their values specified?

Comment: Solve the two equations to get $x(\lambda)$ and $y(\lambda)$. Plug them in the constraint which is an equation in $\lambda$. Solve it and then back to $x$ and $y$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici While that is doable, the resulting quartic for $\lambda$ isn't. Though I'm having trouble findin a method that doesn't end with a quartic for something.

Comment: @eyeballfrog. I agree for sure with you. Just admit that we have a solver for that. in fact, this is often a problem with Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici While i agree the quartic formula exists, its so massively unwieldy that it might as well not. That said, i suppose you could take the expressions for x and y, plug them into F, and use the quartic to reduce it to a (probably hideous) quadratic rational function of $\lambda$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I get these values from the least squares method)

Comment: @eyeballfrog. I fully disagree with you ! It will not be an *"hideous quadratic rational function"* at all ! It will be a $\color{red}{\large\text{Monster}}$. Cheers :-)

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, I mean $a_{4}y^2$. I try to find minimum of my function with this constraint.